# How to cut the circuit when power is back, join otherwise

Tags: ac, circuit-design

I have a fan which runs on 220V AC power supply.

- When the power is there, I use my air conditioner and don't use the fan.
- When the power trips, I want to turn on the Fan automatically using the Inverter.
- I have an **on/off switch** which stops this automation entirely if it is off.

Have a look at the circuit diagram, I tried to draw the situation in that.

So I was developing a circuit but all the solutions are using some kind of a battery. Is there any way to solve it without a battery? Or If battery is necessary, can you help me with a simple circuit to accomplish this.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to turn on a fan specifically when you do not have power available to run it?

Comment: @kanoo Yes exactly, using the inverter. And turn it off when the power comes back

Comment: Inverter circuits require a power source to generate the 'on' signal. You will need a battery. Here is a simple digital 'NOT' circuit: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.electronics-tutorials.ws%2Flogic%2Flogic_4.html&psig=AOvVaw0mMt-jA0KP5K1xkF5DmpiH&ust=1601833481389000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCOiv7PH8mOwCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An 'NC' contact of a contactor or relay, energised by the utility supply, is to be used to bypass the fan switch and automatically switch it on when the inverter is enabled.

[image]

Since mains wiring is involved, it would be advisable for the modification to be carried out only by competent personnel.

Answer (score 0):

Use a relay, with a 220V AC coil.  Connect the coil across the main supply so that it's on when there is power, and off when there isn't.

Use the Common and NC (normally closed) contacts on the relay as the switch to turn the fan on.